# Changing string to UTC to dateTime object

Tags: python, string, date, datetime

I have `time = '2020-06-24T13:30:00-04:00'`. How can I change it to a dateTime object in UTC time. I would prefer not to use `pd.Timestamp(time).tz_convert("UTC").to_pydatetime()` because it returns a weird output that would look like this `datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 24, 17, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>)`. As a result, when I check for equality with `datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 24, 17, 30)`, it return False.

**Edit:**

```py
import datetime
import pytz

time = '2020-06-24T13:30:00-04:00

dt = datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 24, 17, 30)
print("dt: ",dt)

so = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z').astimezone(pytz.utc)
print("so:",so)

print(dt == so)
```

outputs

```
dt: 2020-06-24 17:30:00
so: 2020-06-24 17:30:00+00:00
False
```

How can I get it to properly evaluate to True?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**#1** Since your string is [ISO 8601](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compatible, use `fromisoformat()` on Python 3.7+:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

s = '2020-06-24T13:30:00-04:00'

dtobj = datetime.fromisoformat(s)
# dtobj
# datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 24, 13, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000)))
```

Note that this will give you a timezone-aware datetime object; the `tzinfo` property is a UTC offset. You can easily convert that to UTC using `astimezone()`:

```
dtobj_utc = dtobj.astimezone(timezone.utc)
# dtobj_utc
# datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 24, 17, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

---

**#2** You can achieve the same with `strptime` (also Python3.7+ according to [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue15873)):

```
dtobj = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
dtobj_utc = dtobj.astimezone(timezone.utc)
# dtobj_utc
# datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 24, 17, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

---

**#3** If you want to turn the result into a naive datetime object, i.e. remove the tzinfo property, replace with `None`:

```
dtobj_utc_naive = dtobj_utc.replace(tzinfo=None)
# dtobj_utc_naive
# datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 24, 17, 30)
```

---

**#4** For older Python versions, you should be able to use `dateutil`'s parser:

```
from dateutil import parser
dtobj = parser.parse(s)
dtobj_utc = dtobj.astimezone(timezone.utc)
dtobj_utc_naive = dtobj_utc.replace(tzinfo=None)
# dtobj_utc_naive
# datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 24, 17, 30)
```

Comment: Are there any benefits to a naive datetime object?

Comment: @Danlo9: good question... it depends. In principle, it is better to have a timezone info, unless you ***know*** (for sure) that ***all*** the datetime objects you work with belong to the ***same*** timezone. Also keep in mind that you shouldn't mix up naive and aware datetime objects - use one or the other consistently (to keep you sane).

Answer (score 0):

Alright so my previous answer was sort of wack because I did not understand your issue entirely so I am rewriting it. You problem is that you are constructing a datetime object from a string and it is timezone aware(UTC). However, whenever you make a datetime object in python, `dt = datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 24, 17, 30)`, it is creating it but with no timezone information (which you can check using .tzinfo on it). All you would need to do is make `dt` timezone aware when you first create it. See below my code snippit.

```
import datetime

time = '2020-06-24T13:30:00-04:00'

dt = datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 24, 17, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

print("dt: ",dt.tzinfo)

so = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')

print("so:",so.tzinfo)

print(dt == so)
```

Comment: This doesn't change the time to UTC though... it returns `2020-06-24 13:30:00-04:00` but I need it to be `2020-06-24 17:30:00`

Comment: I would suggest making what you are comparing it to timezone aware to then compare.

Comment: That entire answer was not optimal take a look at the new answer.

Comment: now you import `pytz`, which you also don't need since there is `datetime.timezone.utc` ;-) Sidenote: datetime.timezone.utc and pytz.utc do **not** compare equal.

Comment: Well that was from previous tests and I did not remove the timezone variable or the pytz import but the code does work properly and the explanation is correct.